# Python, How to add more choices in an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a python program with an if statement.  I want to add more choices to the if statement, how do I do it?

```
def start():

    print ("A Wise man once said ...")
    o1 = input("\n" + 
      "[L]ook to the poverty of Africa ... [T]HIS HAS YET TO BE WRITTEN")

    if o1 == "L" or "l" or "Africa" or "1":
        print ("\n" + "You decide only a radical solution is viable...")
    else:
        print ("THIS IS NOT WRITTEN YET")

def menu ():

    print ("Menu\n")
    print ("(1)Start")
    print ("(2)Exit\n\n")
    choice = (input('>>'))
    if choice=="1":
        start()
    if choice=="2":
        quit()

menu()
```

I am trying to make this option next:

```
o2 = input (
  "\n" + "[D]ecide to take advantage ..., or T[H]IS HAS YET TO BE WRITTEN?"*)
```

How should I go about adding more options and choices so that I end up with a story?

Comment: Are you using your `menu` function at all? If not, I think you're on the right lines with that - you could pass a list of options into the menu, along with callables to be executed if the user chooses that option.

Comment: It's not about syntax, it's about how you structure the program. Are you just learning programming? If it's so, I would suggest taking some free online courses (which are numerous now, just a few *platforms*: khan academy, Coursera, Udacity, edX, etc.)

Comment: Or Codeacademy, they have a Python course.

Comment: On a related note, OP might want to take a look at http://kooneiform.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/writing-interactive-fiction-in-python-1/  and http://pythonhosted.org/tale/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of good ways to do this, but I would make a class (lets call it "option_node") that uses dictionaries. The class would hold the text of the prompt, then a dictionary that mapped the text options to other option_nodes or a special option node that ends the dialog.

```
class option_node:
    def __init__(self, prompt):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.options = {}

    def add_option(self, option_text, next_node):
        self.options[option_text] = next_node

    def print_prompt(self):
        print(prompt)

    def select_input(self):
        for each in self.options:
            print(each)
        while(True)
            user_input = input(">>")
            if self.options.get(in):
                return self.options.get(in)


def main():
    nodes = []
    nodes.append(option_node("Welcome"))
    nodes.append(option_node("Stay Awhile"))
    nodes.append(option_node("That's fine, I don't like you much either"))

    nodes[0].add_option("Hello friend", nodes[1])
    nodes[0].add_option("Hello enemy", nodes[2])

    nodes[1].options = None
    nodes[2].options = None

    current_node = nodes[0]
    while current_node.options is not None:
        current_node.print_prompt()
        current_node = current_node.select_input()
```

Hope this helps. I can elaborate more if you'd like

Comment: An elaboration would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: I added a bit more. I haven't tested this sample, but it should demonstrate how to use the class I've created to build some type of conversational flow.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new condition using `elif` (else if):

```
if ...
elif o1 == "D" or o1 == "H":
    # your code here
else ...
```

By the way, you have a syntax error in your conditional statement. Correct it to this:

```
if o1 == "L" or o1 == "l" or o1 == "Africa" or o1 == "1":
```

If it makes it easier, look at it this way:

```
if (o1 == "L") or (o1 == "l") or (o1 == "Africa") or (o1 == "1"):
```

You should think about the order of operations in your statements. `or` has higher precedence than `==`; additionally, the meaning of `"L" or "l"` is not what you think it is.

```
>>> if "L" or "l":
...    print("foo")
...
foo
```

Curious, no? Try some of this stuff out for yourself at the interpreter.